# div not showing during animation using nganimate

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I am trying to make my div2 show up similar to SlideUp-Click to Toggle button [here](http://ng.malsup.com/#!/css-animations-for-ng-hide_ng-show).

My [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/QY1VQVqHPZZOOi9qyl6f?p=preview) shows its not working. The buttons "open second div" and "hide this div" are meant to show/hide the second div. The show/hide does work but the animation does not. Please help.

```
    var myElement = angular.element( document.querySelector('#div2') );
    myElement.addClass('ng-hide');

    $scope.openSecondDiv = function() {
        var myElement = angular.element( document.querySelector('#div2') );
        myElement.removeClass('ng-hide');
    }
    $scope.hideSecondDiv = function() {
        var myElement = angular.element( document.querySelector('#div2') );
        myElement.addClass('ng-hide');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of all the controller logic, what about using ng-show directly as an attribute:

```
<div class="row teal" id="div1">
    <button class="btn" ng-click="showDiv2 = !showDiv2">Open second div</button>
</div>

<div style="background: orange;" class="row cssSlideUp" ng-show='showDiv2'>
    <button class="btn" ng-click="showDiv2 = false">Hide this div</button>
</div>
```

For the ng-clicks, the first is an example of toggling and the other forces it to false.

Comment: can you help me figure out why my code is not working ? I am looking to understand that as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're trying to transition to `height: 0`, which you can't do.

Changing `height` to `max-height` solves the issue with your code as seen in the updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/O4rT2bSsr3KnufQMYuhx?p=preview

But as others have said, you should not be doing it this way. You should just be toggling classes with Angular and not `.addClass`.

Comment: thanks a lot. As per your suggestions i changed the code to animate ng-hide using expressions which is more elegant than the jquery approach i used before. http://plnkr.co/edit/QY1VQVqHPZZOOi9qyl6f?p=preview   
Can you help me understand why we had to change height to max-height. I tried to google but could not figure out

Comment: @Tarun I don't actually know the true answer to this other than Browsers do not support transitioning to a Height of 0 or auto. Think it has something to do with the browser needing actual values to calculate the animation inbetweens.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do such complex for that . I have implemented using simple css transition and ng-class  .

You can check [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/p0wlrv32ghVrQBq2LUnH?p=preview)

My `css` implementation:

```
div {
    white-space: pre;
    background: #eee;
    color: #333;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:0;
    opacity:0;
    transition:height 1s, opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition:height 1s opacity 1s;
    -webkit-transition:height 1s opacity 1s;
    -o-transition:height 1s opacity 1s;
    -ms-transition:height 1s opacity 1s;
}
.changed {
    height:200px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

My `html` implementation

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="hideSecondDiv()">Hide this div</button>
<div ng-class="{changed:clicked === true}" id="div2">

</div>
```

Hope this will work for you .

Comment: can you help me figure out why my code is not working ? I am looking to understand that as well. Thank you for sharing your plunker

Comment: all i want say is your approach isn't good even if it may achieve what you are trying to get. id based dom manipulation , adding/removing class by jquery approach isn't a good approach and when you can achieve same thing in cleaner and more effective way in angular way .

Comment: seems like neither of us know why my code doesnt work .I will try to figure it out.